# Statistically Significant Four Factor Alpha for Monthly Returns Regression but non stat sig alpha for Daily Returns. Which one should I trust?

Tags: factor-models

```
SUMMARY OUTPUT                  
                    
Regression Statistics                   
Multiple R  0.918998992             
R Square    0.844559147             
Adjusted R Square   83.8%               
Standard Error  0.016734114             
Observations    94              
                    
ANOVA                   
    df  SS  MS  F   Significance F
Regression  4   0.13541299  0.033853248 120.8912625 4.08362E-35
Residual    89  0.02492272  0.000280031     
Total   93  0.16033571          
                    
    Coefficients    Standard Error  t Stat  P-value 
Intercept   0.49%   0.00156481  3.114167288 0.25%   
SMB 0.078908101 0.048220136 1.636413884 10.53%  
HML -0.083405428    0.039201937 -2.127584361    3.61%   
WML -0.132884557    0.030054328 -4.4214783  0.00%   
70% India 30% USA Minus RF  0.892777286 0.07200324  12.39912652 0.00%   

SUMMARY OUTPUT                  
                    
Regression Statistics                   
Multiple R  0.704712899             
R Square    0.49662027              
Adjusted R Square   50%             
Standard Error  0.005459587             
Observations    1928                
                    
ANOVA                   
    df  SS  MS  F   Significance F
Regression  4   0.056549346 0.014137336 474.2944151 1.1288E-284
Residual    1923    0.057319035 2.98071E-05     
Total   1927    0.113868381         
                    
    Coefficients    Standard Error  t Stat  P-value 
Intercept   0.02%   0.000102977 2.371487639 1.78%   
SMB     0.124288777 0.02670111  4.654816873 0.00%   
HML     0.052914661 0.018226336 2.903197921 0.37%   
WML     -0.003336562    0.019884054 -0.167800906    86.68%  
70% India 30% USA Minus RF  0.634035625 0.037499927 16.90764944 0.00%
```

I have used Newey West Estimator to correct for autocorrelation and heteroscadicity in both regressions. Both regressions were done using Excel. The first output is the monthly returns regression and second is daily returns regression. I am considering a p-value of less than 1% as statistically significant. The output is from "Regression" which is part of Excel Data Analysis Addon. Only modifications I done was input the HAC standard errors for Market Beta, SMB, HML,WML and Intercept (which also effects the t-stat and p-values of these coeffiecients) as the Excel Regression is OLS.